# Fortran OpenACC invoking a function on device using a function pointer

Tags: fortran, function-pointers, openacc

How can I access a function on device via a function pointer?

In below code I am trying to access `init0` or `init1` using function pointer `init`. The code does work as intended if OpenACC is not enabled during compilation. However, it fails when compiled with OpenACC. Below code is saved as `stackOverflow2.f95`:

```
module modTest2

  use openacc
  implicit none

  
  type :: Container
    sequence
    integer :: n
    integer, allocatable :: arr(:)
  end type Container


  interface Container
    procedure :: new_Container
  end interface 


  abstract interface
    integer function function_template (i)
      integer, intent (in) :: i
    end function function_template
  end interface


  contains
  
    type(Container) function new_Container(n)
      integer, intent(in) :: n

      allocate(new_Container%arr(n))
    end function new_Container    
end module modTest2

program test2

  use modTest2
  implicit none


  integer :: n, x, i
  type(Container) :: c
  procedure(function_template), pointer :: init


  print *, "Enter array size: "
  read *, n
  print *, "Allocating..."
  c = Container(n)
  print *, "Allocation complete!"
  
  
  print *, "Enter initialization type (x): "
  read *, x
  print *, "Initializing..."
  select case (x)
    case (0)
      init => init0
    case default
      init => init1
  end select
  !$acc data copyin(c) copyout(c%arr)
  !$acc parallel loop present(c)
  do i = 1, n
    c%arr(i) = init(i)
  end do
  !$acc end data
  print *, "Initialization complete..."


  do i = 1, n
    print *, i, c%arr(i)
  end do
  
  
  contains
  
    integer function init0(i)
      !$acc routine
      integer, intent(in) :: i
      init0 = 10*i
    end function init0

    
    integer function init1(i)
      !$acc routine
      integer, intent(in) :: i
      init1 = 20*i
    end function init1
end program test2
```

Correct output is seen without OpenACC:

```
$ gfortran -c stackOverflow2.f95
$ gfortran stackOverflow2.o -o a.out
$ ./a.out
 Enter array size: 
3
 Allocating...
 Allocation complete!
 Enter initialization type (x): 
0
 Initializing...
 Initialization complete...
           1          10
           2          20
           3          30
```

Incorrect output is seen below with OpenACC (Note that NVIDIA compiler is used here):

```
$ /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/22.1/compilers/bin/nvfortran stackOverflow2.f95 -acc; ./a.out
 Enter array size: 
3
 Allocating...
 Allocation complete!
 Enter initialization type (x): 
0
 Initializing...
 Initialization complete...
            1            0
            2            0
            3            0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gfortran-11` with the below did the trick:

```
module modTest2

  use openacc
  implicit none

  
  type :: Container
    sequence
    integer :: n
    integer, allocatable :: arr(:)
  end type Container


  interface Container
    procedure :: new_Container
  end interface 


  abstract interface
    integer function function_template (i)
      integer, intent (in) :: i
    end function function_template
  end interface


  contains
  
    type(Container) function new_Container(n)
      integer, intent(in) :: n

      allocate(new_Container%arr(n))
    end function new_Container    
end module modTest2

program test2

  use modTest2
  implicit none


  integer :: n, x, i
  type(Container) :: c
  procedure(function_template), pointer :: init


  print *, "Enter array size: "
  read *, n
  print *, "Allocating..."
  c = Container(n)
  print *, "Allocation complete!"
  
  
  print *, "Enter initialization type (x): "
  read *, x
  print *, "Initializing..."
  select case (x)
    case (0)
      init => init0
    case default
      init => init1
  end select
  !$acc enter data copyin(c)
  !$acc enter data create(c%arr)
  !$acc parallel loop present(c)
  do i = 1, n
    c%arr(i) = init(i)
  end do
  !$acc exit data copyout(c%arr)
  !$acc exit data delete(c)
  print *, "Initialization complete..."


  do i = 1, n
    print *, i, c%arr(i)
  end do
  
  
  contains
  
    integer function init0(i)
      !$acc routine
      integer, intent(in) :: i
      init0 = 10*i
    end function init0

    
    integer function init1(i)
      !$acc routine
      integer, intent(in) :: i
      init1 = 20*i
    end function init1
end program test2
```

Here's the output:

```
$ gfortran-11 -fopenacc stackOverflow2.f95
$ gfortran-11 -fopenacc stackOverflow2.o -o stackOverflow2
$ ./stackOverflow2 
 Enter array size: 
4
 Allocating...
 Allocation complete!
 Enter initialization type (x): 
0
 Initializing...
 Initialization complete...
           1          10
           2          20
           3          30
           4          40
$ ./stackOverflow2 
 Enter array size: 
4
 Allocating...
 Allocation complete!
 Enter initialization type (x): 
9
 Initializing...
 Initialization complete...
           1          20
           2          40
           3          60
           4          80
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but function pointers (along with C++ virtual functions) are not yet supported on the device.  Adding the compiler feedback flag (-Minfo=accel), you'll see the following message:

```
% nvfortran -acc -Minfo=accel test.f90
test2:
     62, Generating copyout(c%arr(:)) [if not already present]
         Generating copyin(c) [if not already present]
     65, Accelerator restriction: Indirect function/procedure calls are not supported
```

The problem being that indirect functions require a device jump table and runtime dynamic linking which is currently unavailable.  While I don't have a timeline, we are exploring options on how to offer this support in the future.